# Java 8 stream api key based merging

Tags: java, merge, java-8, java-stream

I've recently started to learn stream API.
I am trying remove duplication from following piece of code. 
Is it possible use merge function based on `Predicate` or condition? 
(Also I was thinking about using `partitioningBy` or `groupingBy` from `Collectors`)

```
BinaryOperator<LocalDateTime> latestDate = (p, a) -> a.isAfter(p) ? a : p;
BinaryOperator<LocalDateTime> earliestDate = (p, a) -> a.isBefore(p) ? a : p;


         Map<Status,LocalDateTime> latest = history.stream()
                    .filter(isNewOrOpen.negate())
                    .collect(toMap(History::getStatus,
                            History::getChangedtetme,
                            latestDate));

        Map<Status,LocalDateTime> earliest = history.stream()
                    .filter(isNewOrOpen)
                    .collect(toMap(History::getStatus,
                            History::getChangedtetme,
                            earliestDate));

            latest.putAll(earliest);
```

Comment: So you have two separate lists, namely `history` and `historyGroup`?

Comment: @TagirValeev They shouldn't be, this is my typo. Changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, `isNewOrOpen` predicate uses `History.getStatus()` and you want to select the history items with earliest date for new/open status and with latest date for other statuses. It's better to define the `Comparator` which implements this logic (it's supposed that `h1` and `h2` have the same status here):

```
Comparator<History> comparator = (h1, h2) -> isNewOrOpen.test(h1) ? 
    h2.getChangedtetme().compareTo(h1.getChangedtetme()):
    h1.getChangedtetme().compareTo(h2.getChangedtetme());
```

Using this comparator, it's quite easy to define the collector to solve your task:

```
Collector<History, ?, Map<Status, LocalDateTime>> collector
        = groupingBy(History::getStatus, 
                collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparator), 
                opt -> opt.get().getChangedtetme()));
```

Note the `collectingAndThen` usage: `maxBy` returns `Optional<History>` and we want to extract the `getChangedtetme()` (whatever it means).

So finally you can use this collector directly:

```
Map<Status, LocalDateTime> result = history.stream().collect(collector);
```

The `latestDate` and `earliestDate` seem to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you can use Collectors.partitioningBy to do what you want.

```
BinaryOperator<LocalDateTime> latestDate = (p, a) -> a.isAfter(p) ? a : p;

Map<Boolean, Map<Status,LocalDateTime>> partitions = 
        history.stream()
               .collect(partitioningBy(isNewOrOpen,
                                       toMap(History::getStatus,
                                       History::getChangedtetme,
                                       latestDate));

Map<Status,LocalDateTime> latest = partitions.get(true);
Map<Status,LocalDateTime> earliest = partitions.get(false);
```

Comment: I think `latestDate` might also be expressible as `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())`.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't obvious from my listing, that I have two BinaryOpertaors(I've already added second one). It does make sense, but I have to use them both depending on status - earliest for New or Open and latest for else.